# Distribute plugin resource files to host project

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

I have a maven plugin that exposes a Mojo, with a goal that runs at the compile stage. The project was generated using mvn archetype:generate, and the POM contains all the standard stuff that comes with running that, very little deviation. The project includes a couple of resource files, e.g. filea.txt and fileb.txt, that are packaged up as part of the jar.

When the plugin is used in a project, I'd like the files that are included in the jar to be extracted and copied to the target\test-classes directory of the host project. I'm trying to use the plugin jar to both distribute some files + expose some functionality that can then use those files.

Is this a valid approach, and if so, are there settings I can add to the plugin POM to indicate that content from the plugin should be extracted and copied? I want to centralise this logic in the plugin, rather than having to do in the plugin host.

I feel like it's something with maven-dependency-plugin or maven-resources-plugin or build-helper-maven-plugin:attach-artifact, have tried a couple of different approaches but think I'm missing something obvious:

e.g. something like this in plugin POM?

```
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/test-classes</outputDirectory>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
              <include>filea.txt</include>
              <include>fileb.txt</include>
            </includes>
          </resource>
        </resources>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.0</version>
    </plugin>
    // etc etc
```

Google fu has let me down, keep ending up on maven resources page. Can post directory structure / more information if needed.

Cheers

Comment: First I would suggest to put resources which needs to be distributed into `src/main/resources`  which looks like you have done ...but remove the configuration for the maven-resources-plugin and let maven do it's work. This is automatically copied into `target/classes/` which in result is packaged into the resulting jar later...If your plugin needs to get those files those can accessed as a usual resource via `this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/...")` and reading and writing them into a new location preferable into `target/...`...

Comment: Yes @khmarbaise, I'm happy with the packaged jar - has the files I need. Ah OK, so as long as those files are in the jar, I should just be able to use this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/...") in my Mojo code and do whatever I need to, which will work from the project hosting the plugin? Let me give that a go

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks - that put me back on track and away from the rabbit hole I was going down. Just needed to refer the the files in the correct way when using getResourceAsStream with the jar, and was able to copy across to target directories. If you change your comment to an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: done say. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would suggest to put resources which needs to be distributed into `src/main/resources` which looks like you have done ...but remove the configuration for the maven-resources-plugin and let maven do it's work. This is automatically copied into `target/classes/` which in result is packaged into the resulting jar later.

If your plugin needs to get those files those can accessed as a usual resource via `this.getClass().getResourcesAsStream("/...")` and reading and writing them into a new location preferable into `target/...`